# Объясните, пожалуйста, ответы. Егэ В часть

Tags: егэ

Здравствуйте!

Скажите пожалуйста, и объясните(самое главное) ответы для работы 
http://forum.postupim.ru/_fr/347/01_142V.pdf

На вопросы:  В1-3 и В5,В7,В8. Я уже просто запутался. Гуглю каждый вопрос, но не могу понять какой ответ. Напишите вкратце ответ и признак(т.е. Как его нашли). Остальные задания писать не надо, сделал сам.

Спасибо!

Comment: Мой антивирус заблокировал сайт, скопируйте в задание нужные места.

Comment: @Людмила, у меня Каперский ничего не блокирует. Ни чем помочь не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В1-защиты, споров(защитить-защита, спорить-спор)

В2-героическое(прилагат. перешло в сущ.-что?-героическое)

В3-давно задумываются (как?-давно -наречие примыкает, т.к. оно не изменяется)

В5-2 как отделить подлинно героическое от лжегероизма?-безличное простое

В7-4-Об этом давно задумываются люди.Об этом - указат мест.

В8-4,9,1,(привязан к галере своего времени), 6(герой не феномен, а обыкновенная личность)

Comment: @Людмила, спасибо.

Comment: @Людмила, мне кажется, Вы не верно сделали номер В5. Ваш ответ верен для номера В4.

Comment: Вы правы, В5-3 (творец подвига),10-обос. приложение-рыцари, состоявших на службе у феодалов